# Can't change color of mesh3d in plotly

Tags: r, colors, plotly, mesh

I've been unsuccessful in changing the color of my mesh in plotly using R.

My code looks like this:

```
 plot_ly() %>%

      add_trace(type = 'mesh3d', x = data.fit$HMT.1, y = data.fit$Droplet, z = data.fit$RS_out1, 
                alphahull=9, opacity=0.4, flatshading = 0,  colorscale=list(list(0, 'purple'), list(1, 'purple'))) %>% # This code creates the 3D hull
      layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(range = c(min(pset2$HMT.1), max(pset2$HMT.1)), title = 'Calor'),
                          yaxis = list(range = c(min(pset2$Droplet), max(pset2$Droplet)), title = 'Tamanho'),
                          zaxis = list(range = c(min(pset2$RS_out1), max(pset2$RS_out1)), title = 'Gordura'))
      )
```

The colors command doesn't seem to be working.
Has anyone had any experience with this?